# How do we know $\pi$ is a constant?

Tags: geometry, math-history, circles, conic-sections

How did the ancient Greeks discover that the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter is constant? It does not seem so intuitive. Thanks!

Comment: I don't *know* the answer [hence why I'm posting this as a comment], but I suspect that it wasn't proved rigorously [at least, not at first]. Rather, I suspect they'll have tested it on loads of circles and thought 'wow, this is, like, the same each time, lol'. But I'm open to being corrected.

Comment: It seems perfectly obvious to me. Like so many important discoveries $-$ Darwin's theory of evolution, for instance $-$ it only needed to be stated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/proof-that-pi-is-constant-the-same-for-all-circles-without-using-limits?rq=1

Comment: How do you know the ratio of a square's circonference to its side is 4?

Comment: It is (and was!) obvious. Archimedes gave what is in essence a formal proof.

Comment: @CliveNewstead The classics would be so much more entertaining if they were interspersed with "lol" and "omg" :)

Comment: I can't believe I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: The idea is that:

Similar polygons inscribed in circles are proportional to the squares on the diameters of the circles. By approximating circles closely by similar polygons, the proportion is carried over to the circles.

This is the way that it was proved by Euclid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably they used an intuitive (or maybe exact) idea of geometric similarity.