# Proof using trigonometry that circle circumference is $2 \pi R$

Tags: trigonometry

Using trigonometry, I would like to prove that the circumference of a circle is $2\pi$ times its radius. Can someone help please?

Comment: How do you define $\pi$?

Comment: In many contexts, $\pi$ is _defined_ as the ratio of circumference to diameter in a circle.  That's actually the most usual definition for maybe more than two centuries now.  I see a couple of questions here: (1) How does one know that that ratio is the same for all circles?, and (2) How does one know that that is the _same_ as the ratio of the area of a circle to the area of the square on its radius?  (Note that I am careful here to refer to the square _on_, rather than _of_ the radius---a distinction that is too often neglected.)

Comment: Following up on my last comment: Nowadays people often take the word "radius" to refer to a _number_: the distance from the center to the curve.  In older usage, a radius is any line segment having one endpoint at the center and the other on the curve.  A square on the radius is a square one of whose sides is the radius.  Those whose reading is restricted only to the curriculum often never find this out, I suspect.  I think in Latin "radius" means a spoke of a wheel (but I could be wrong about that).

Answer (score 10):

The question as it stands is not well posed as you are asking the wrong question.  In order to prove that the circumference formula $C = 2\pi r$ holds for all circle of radius $r$, we first have to understand what $\pi$ is.

First, let's discuss what $\pi$ is not.  In grade school, $\pi$ is typically defined as a number which is about $3.14159\dots$  In reality, $\pi$ is more than just a number.  It is *defined* as the proportion of a circle's circumference to its diameter.  First, we need to ask ourselves: **Why is that no matter what diameter of a circle we have, the ratio of the circumference to the diameter are always the same?** The answer to this question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/proof-that-pi-is-constant-the-same-for-all-circles-without-using-limits), [here](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Proof:_Pi_is_Constant), or at [any of these links via a google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=proof%20that%20ratio%20of%20circumference%20to%20diameter%20is%20constant&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).  Once we know that the circumference of a circle and its diameter are always proportional, then we can ask: **What is the [proportionality constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_%28mathematics%29)?**  This amounts to precisely evaluating digits of pi, [which is a computation problem](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=computing%20digits%20of%20pi&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

With these two question behind us, your original question now answers itself.  We have $C = 2 \pi r$, since $\pi = \frac{C}{d} = \frac{C}{2r}$ by definition.

Comment: I should also mention that Michael Hardy mentioned that the circumference of a circle and its length are often confused, and I admit that I use the two terms interchangeably here.  What I give up in precision, I make up for in getting my point across.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If we divide an $n$ sided equilateral polygon into $n$ triangles (which are generated by the lines to centre from the vertices), the angle at the centre $\frac{2\pi}n$

Let each side be $x$ and the distance from the centre to any vertex be $r$

The rest two angles are same $=\theta$(say)

So, $2\theta=\pi-\frac{2\pi}n\implies \theta =\frac\pi2-\frac\pi n$

Now, using Sine Law of triangle, $$\frac r{\sin \left(\frac\pi2-\frac\pi n\right) }=\frac x{\sin \frac{2\pi}n}$$
$$\implies x=\frac{\sin \frac{2\pi}n}{\cos \frac\pi n }=2r\sin\frac\pi n  $$

Now, the circumference $=n\cdot 2r\sin\frac\pi n $

Now, the polygon will become a circle if $n\to\infty$

Comment: What is $\pi$ if not the ratio of a circle's circumference to the length of its diameter?

Comment: The very last step is extremely problematic since lengths don't behave very nicely with respect to taking limits. The length function is only upper semi-continuous.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, how about http://www.maa.org/joma/volume7/aktumen/Polygon.html or the Step n: Using an n-sided polygon of http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math101/notes/integration/archimedes.html

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'm not sure what these links are supposed to relate to. Can you perhaps clarify?

Comment: @IttayWeiss, the idea is to start with a regular polygon and if the number of sides $\to\infty,$ it approximates to a circle

Comment: @labbhattacharjee but length is not a continuos operation. So, the fact that a sequence of curves (even uniformly) converges to a given curve does not imply the lengths converge to the length of the curve.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot \sin\frac\pi n=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin \pi h}h=\pi$$ So, the perimeter turns out to be $2\pi r$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee you keep ignoring the fact that length is not continuous. The fact that the polygons approach the circle does *not* imply that the lengths of the polygons approach the length of the circle.