# Another Method to Prove the Circumference of a Circle with Arc Length Integration

Tags: integration, geometry, circles, arc-length

I'm trying to prove that the circumference of a circle is $C=2\pi r$. There are other simple ways to prove it, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394821/proof-using-trigonometry-that-circle-circumference-is-2-pi-r), such as just giving a definition to $\pi$, but I thought I would overcomplicate it and employ the arc length integral, as shown below.

$$s=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx$$

Note that my strategy is to find the length of half the circle, then double the result. The derivative of the graph of a semi-circle, $y=\sqrt{{1+x}^2}$ is, according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5Bd%2Cdx%5DSqrt%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D),

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

So $1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$. Plugging this into the integral, I expected to get $\pi r$. [Instead I got](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2CSqrt%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-r%2Cr%7D%5D)

$$\int_{-r}^r \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = 2\sin^{-1}(r)$$

Could someone please explain where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: For me it is not $y=\sqrt{{1+x}^2}$ but the semi-circle is $y=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: I add that is $y=+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ where $r>0$ is the radius.

Comment: But that doesn't change the result.

Comment: But it does change the result. $\int_{-r}^r dx/\sqrt{r^2-x^2} = \pi r$ as expected.

Comment: Thanks! I overlooked that.

Comment: Alternatively $ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2$ simplifies to $ds=rd\theta$.

Comment: Right, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

$$\int_{-r}^r \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx=\int_{-r}^r \frac{r\,dx}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}=\int_{-r}^r \frac{r\,dx}{\sqrt{1-(x/r)^2}}$$
We will use the change of variables

$t=\frac xr \implies \frac{dt}{dx}=\frac 1r$. After $rdt=dx$ and if $x = −r → u = −1$, $x = r → u = 1$. Hence
$$\int_{-r}^r \frac{r\,dx}{\sqrt{1-(x/r)^2}}=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{r\,du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=r\arcsin u\Bigl|_{-1}^{1}=r\left( \frac {\pi}2+ \frac {\pi}2\right)=r\pi$$

**Addendum**: In your case $r=1$ hence $$\int _{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\left[\arcsin \left(x\right)\right]_{-1}^1=\pi.$$

Comment: I know this question is pretty old but could you explain why you set $t=\frac{x}{r}$? It didn't seem to help you evaluate the integral at all.

Comment: @Gordon Because I have $\int_{-r}^r \frac{r\,dx}{\sqrt{1-(x/r)^2}}$. In the specific $x/r$.

Comment: But you changed it to $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{rdu}{\sqrt{(1-u^2)}}, so  $du=dx$  and 
 $u=x/r},$ right? Sorry I'm just trying to make sense of it myself.

Comment: @Gordon I do the derivate of $t=x/r$ (integration by substitution).

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem borders on the trivial when viewed in the complex plane. The arc length is given by

$$
s=\int |\dot z|\ du
$$

Now, for you case we have

$$
z=re^{i\theta}\\
\dot z=ire^{i\theta}\\
|\dot z|=r
$$

So that
$$
s=\int_0^{2\pi} |\dot z|\ d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi} r\ d\theta=2\pi r
$$

Comment: Interesting method.

Comment: @Gordon The interesting thing is that this works for *any* closed curves, which is something that cannot be said for working in the Cartesian plane.

Comment: Hmm. I should spend time studying this.

Comment: Question: How did you get $z=re^{iθ}$?

Comment: @Gordon $z=re^{i\theta}$ is the very definition of a circle of radius $r$  centered at the origin in the the complex plane. $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, so if you plot $x=\cos\theta$ vs $y=\sin\theta$ for $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$ you will get a circle.

Comment: Okay thank you.