# Explicit formulas for the length of the circumference of a circle of radius $R$

Tags: geometry

After reading some articles about how Archimedes used to approximate $\pi$ and doing some math, I found out that the following formula spits out the length of the circumference $C(R)$ of a circle of radius $R$ (here $a_n=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-a^2_{n-1}}}$ with $a_1=1$):
$$C(R)=3R\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(2^n a_{n-1})}$$
(The awesome thing is that it doesn't involve $\pi$ at all, so it can actually be used to [prove that $\pi$ is in fact constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/proof-that-pi-is-constant-the-same-for-all-circles-without-using-limits).)
Are there any other explicit formulas for the length of the circumference of a circle of radius $R$ that don't involve $\pi$ in any way? It would be awesome if they involve $e$, $i$ or $\phi$ or some other neat constants in a nontrivial way (so don't post the formula above with $\frac{e}{e}$ outfront and things like that).

Comment: You have given a starting point for the relation with $a_1 = 1$ but have not defined any sort of recurrence, eg $a_n = f(a_{n-1})$ so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user157545 my bad, fixed.

Comment: There are huge numbers of formulae of this type.  For a start try [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html).

Comment: $\pi=-i\cdot\ln(-1)$