Strict proof of infinitesimal equivalency between $\sin{x}$ and $x$
When I was teaching infinitesimal equivalency between $\sin(x)$ and $x$ ($x\rightarrow0$) for Calculus, I realized that it was not very easy to have a pure elementary proof for it without using the area formula for sectors. Indeed, the area formula for sectors itself can be derived by this equivalency. It seems that we have a circular argument here. A very smart student suggested that we can simply use the fact that among all shapes with a fixed perimeter the disk has the largest area. She further gave a proof sketch for this statement by symmetry and the fact that when one makes two edges of a triangle orthogonal then its area is increased.
I am wondering if there is any other proof of this equivalency with or without using advanced concepts in Calculus? The difficulty here is that this equivalency is so fundamental in Calculus that many other results (e.g., the derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$) are based on it so cannot be used to prove it. Meanwhile, elementary mathematics is quite unable to deal with curves.

I don't think sector area derives by this equivalence, sector area can be proved by only using circle area and no trigonometric functions

The proof depends heavily on your definition of $\sin$.  The proof using the trigonometric function typically amounts to showing $\sin x \leq x \leq \tan x$ for $0 < x < \pi/2$.  Is that what you're asking about?

@BrianMoehring Yes, I am asking about the step $x\le\tan(x)$.

@VincenzoTibullo I think a strict calculation of the circle area still requires this equivalence? If we do integration, then we need to use the derivative of sin(x), otherwise approximation by polygons still uses this equivalence.

@KeqinLiu'Kevin' the area of a sector of angle $\alpha$ is a fraction $\alpha/2\pi$ of the area of the whole circle. The area of the circle has been proved by Archimedes to be $\pi r^2$. No integration or trigonometry required.

@VincenzoTibullo I belief Archimedes's proof still assumes $\sin x\sim x$ otherwise one cannot straighten an arc.

@BrianMoehring Yes, but I still need $\sin x\sim x$. How do you do it without this?

@KeqinLiu'Kevin' I don't think Archimedes at his time know about $\sin$ function

@VincenzoTibullo I agree. That is why I am looking for a strict proof.

@BrianMoehring Arcs not getting far from chords does not mean arc lengths not getting far from chord lengths.

Okay, I think I finally understand your question.  It seems Archimedes' proof views the prerequisite assumption as a postulate rather than something to be proven (effectively saying "since the polygon has a larger perimeter than the inscribed circle [...]").  It does make your question even more reductive though: "What do you mean by the 'perimeter' of a circle?"

@BrianMoehring You are right! The definition of arc length itself requires something beyond elementary mathematics. In other words, we have to accept something (e.g., the arc length is defined as the limit of the Riemann sum of the lengths of small line segments if the limit exists) as an axiom/definition at least...

In short, a modern definition would use analytic geometry and calculus to prove that the arc-length exists, define it to be equal to $2\pi$, and then prove that the integral for the area equals $\pi$.  In doing so, we avoid circular arguments by not dealing with trig substitutions but rather properties of the integrals themselves.

Based on where this question led, I am tempted to link https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2929627/694754 and mark this as a duplicate, though obviously it wouldn't be apparent from the original question.

@BrianMoehring Exactly. But when I was learning differential geometry, I had troubles in accepting the definition of arc length. It is just not as clear to me as other concepts...

@BrianMoehring Sure. Thanks for pointing out the original question.

I'm posting an answer to summarize the rather long comment thread before it likely gets moved to chat.  In short, the problem in the question reduced to the fact that most classical proofs that the area of the unit circle is $\pi$ implicitly use $\theta \leq \tan \theta$ for $\theta \in (0,\pi/2)$.  Then, the typical proof that $\theta \leq \tan \theta$ uses that the area of the unit circle is $\pi$, which is arguably circular.
For example:

Archimedes's proof essentially says "Since the perimeter of the polygon is greater than the circumference of the inscribed circle [...]"
The usual proof of partitioning the circle into circular sectors and rearranging into a parallelogram/rectangle often just claims the length is $\pi$ by fiat (e.g. wikipedia's entry on the area of the circle does this) without mentioning it's actually $\pi \frac{\sin\delta_n}{\delta_n}$ for an appropriate $\delta_n$.


The problem with a modern, formal proof is "what do we even mean by the perimeter of the circle?"  To answer this, we need some calculus.
In short, when it exists, we define the arc-length of the curve $\{(t,f(t)) : t \in [a,b]\}$ to be $$\int_a^b\sqrt{1 + (f'(t))^2}\,dt$$
(alternatively, we could define arc-length differently and then prove this as a theorem; all that matters is this formula gives something that extends polygonal "perimeter" in a natural way and it is sufficiently general for our purposes in this problem)
To consider the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, we use $y = f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$.  Then the circumference of the circle can be taken as the definition of $2\pi$, so that
$$\begin{align*}\pi &:= \int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2}\,dx \\ &= 2\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx\end{align*}$$
The area of the circle, $A$, is given by
$$\begin{align*}
A &= 2\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx \\ 
&= 4\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx \\
&= 2\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx + 2\int_0^1 (x)'\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx \\
&= 2\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx - 2\int_0^1 x\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)'\,dx \\
&= 2\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx + 2\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx \\
&= 2\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{1-x^2} + \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\,dx \\
&= 2\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx \\ &= \pi
\end{align*}$$
Note that this also proves that $\pi < \infty$ and therefore the corresponding arc-length integral exists (which possibly wasn't obvious from the original definition) as $A \leq 4$ since the circle sits inside the square $[-1,1]^2$

Actually, the definition of arc length in modern calculus already implies that sin(x) is an infinitesimal equivalency of x. So I think people should not prove this statement based on methods like comparing areas. Instead, we should just teach students that modern calculus is entirely based on the idea of 'local linearization' followed by statements as mentioned in this question.

This is a way that I discovered it myself, when I was back in Grade 7.
Take a unit circle($r=1$). Inscribe a cyclic regular polygon in it( it's vertices must lie on the circle). The circle will act as the circumcircle of the polygon. It's well known that an $n$ sided regular polygon can be divided into $n$ isoceles triangles, like this:-

Let $\angle CAD=2x=\frac{2π}{n}$.
By basic trigonometry, we can say that $CD=2×\sin x$. Thus perimeter of the polygon=$n×(2\sin x)=2n\sin x$.
Now, as $x→0, 2n \sin x→2π$
But $2π=2xn$, so $2n \sin x→2xn$ and thus $\sin x→x$.

Arguably the entire question is about formally justifying "$2n \sin x \to 2\pi$".  Depending on your view, you might argue whether this is a meaningful question, but we still have to meet the question asker where they are.

@BrianMoehring was I supposed to justify $pi$? I have read the thread. I don't seem to understand the question?
